# c# Trying to loop through a string array , compare a string to find, and output the found string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, search, compare

A program to find a book in an array of books. This code doesn't find the book?

```
string aBookToFind;
string[] listOfBooks = { "Jane Eyre", "Catch22", "Dunkirk","Kidnapped", "Treasure Island" };
aBookToFind=Console.ReadLine();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
Console.WriteLine("Book : "+listOfBooks[i]);
if (aBookToFind == listOfBooks[i])
{Console.WriteLine("Found Book "+ listOfBooks[i];
}
}
```

Comment: Which book you are trying to find?

Comment: What, exactly, are you typing into the console? Put a screenshot of what you have typed, just before you hit enter

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing parentheses at line 7 before the ";"
`{Console.WriteLine("Found Book "+ listOfBooks[i];`
After fixing this and running the code with the Input: `Catch22`
The Output was:

```
Book : Jane Eyre
Book : Catch22
Found Book Catch22
Book : Dunkirk
Book : Kidnapped
Book : Treasure Island
```

So I'd say other than the missing ")" it's working as expected.
If you expected another output, maybe add it to your question for a more precise answer.